# change to binary without arrays

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation

I am trying to change a digit to binary without using arrays. For example:

when x is `7`
print `00000111`

This code that I made outputs `11100000`. I have trouble reversing it.

```
   int x=7;
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%d", x % 2);
        x = x / 2;
    }
```

Comment: NOTE: `scanf("%d", &x);`  the`%d` format expects a pointer to **int** as an argument.`x` is a character.

Comment: You should look into [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Your system appears to be a little endian system and you will need to reverse the order in which you scan the variable in your loop.

Comment: @SimonDoppler: The endianness in the C implementation is not relevant to this question.

Comment: "without using arrays" --> note that code uses `"%d"`, a _string literal_, which is an array.

Comment: What output should be expected  with input like `-1` or `1234567`? Or is that a "don't care".

Comment: So basically your question is "how do I loop from 7 to 0 instead of from 0 to 7"?

Comment: @Anti Haapala Not exactly. I want to print the result of my code on the console in a reverse order.

Comment: @SHM Better to append those requirements to the question than only in the comments.

Comment: @SHM, If you require "(-128~127) which char can handle", sounds like you want `signed char` and not `char`.  `char` could be like `unsigned char` with a range like [0...255].

Answer (score 2):

There a multiple problems in your code:

- You have undefined behavior in your input method: the `scanf` format `%d` expects the address of an `int`, whereas `x` is defined as a `char`.
- you should not use `char` to store a byte value. an `unsigned char` or an `int` i a better choice.
- you should test if `scanf()` was given valid input.
- you should output the bits from the highest to the lowest order.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x;
    if (scanf("%d", &x) == 1) {
        for (int mask = 128; mask != 0; mask = mask / 2) {
            printf("%d", (x & mask) != 0);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: we are in 2019, I think you could write `for (int mask = 128; ...`

Comment: @Stargateur: indeed I could. I just edited the OP's code with an extra test for `scanf()` success...

Comment: and you make it a multiple declaration just for trigger me ? ;) well your answer but I still think you should update your style to something more modern and safe.

Comment: @Stargateur: I shall concede for this one. But I do not like the `for` initializer declaration scope: I think it is inconsistent that it does not extend beyond the end of the statement, like any other block scoped definition.

Comment: @chqrlie it is actually rather consistent - even `if`, `while` etc start their own scope, but they just don't allow declarations. And unlike in C++, you can shadow the variable names *within* the statement block, which has its own scope. [An example about `if` scoping here](https://godbolt.org/z/joFLVQ)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: interesting `if` scoping example. Learn something new everyday I guess :) I insist that this scope seems inconsistent with the language of the C Standard. **C17 6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers** *Every other identifier has scope determined by the placement of its declaration (in a declarator or type specifier). If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears outside of any block or list of parameters, the identifier has file scope, which terminates at the end of the translation unit. ...*

Comment: ... *If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the associated block. If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears within the list of parameter declarations in a function prototype (not part of a function definition), the identifier has function prototype scope, which terminates at the end of the function declarator.* ...

Comment: ... *If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will end strictly before the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). Within the inner scope, the identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.*

Comment: The problem is the definition of the term *block*. Compound statements are blocks, but also selection and iteration statements, which is counter-intuitive because many programmers use the word *block* to refer to compound statements only.

Comment: @chqrlie this was a change from C89 actually, the code does compile in C89 mode. That's also why VC6 did the scoping oddly because it didn't obey the C99 scoping at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can first reverse you initial number in such a way that its ith bit is at position 7-i.

This can be done with the following code :

```
int bit_reverse(char x)
{
   int r=0;
   for (int i=0; i<8; i++){
      r=2*r + x%2;
      x=x/2;
   }
   return r;
}
```

Actually, the function uses integer r as a stack. First extracted bits are pushed toward the higher positions by successive multiplications by 2.

Then, you just have to apply your initial code to what returns the bit_reverse function.

```
int main(){
  int x;
  scanf("%d", &x);
  int r=bit_reverse(x);
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<8;i++){
    printf("%d",r%2);
    r=r/2;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please consider enabling compiler warnings, and test your code

Comment: Your `bit_reverse` is totally b0rken. In fact it never even ends. And `%d` requires a pointer to `int`.

Comment: Right. I corrected it. I should have checked before and not copy past OP function without checking it. Thanks for reporting the problem.

Answer (score -1):

As you don't want to store the temp result of every digital, in fact the first digital you get would print last, that's a `LIFO`. You can use a recursion to emulate a stack like control flow.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int print_binary(unsigned char x, int num) {
  if ( num == 0) {
    printf("%d",x);  
    return 0;
  }
  print_binary(x/2, num-1);
  printf("%d",x%2);         /* print this digital only after finding other ones */ 
  return 0;
}


int main() {
  char x;
  scanf("%d",&x);
  print_binary(x,7);   /* iteration takes up to 8 times */
}
```

Comment: Negative input results in `'-'` in output, yet OP has unclear goals in that case,

Comment: True,  i guess the scope would be `unsigned` int and < 256 (from defining x as `char`), thus hard-codes 8 step recursion, `scanf` should not use `%d` in this case, either

Comment: *** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated

Comment: `char x;
  scanf("%d",&x);` --> `int x;
  scanf("%d",&x);`